# when i am upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The terminal is showing this error. Please resolve this

Tags: mysql, dependencies

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.32-1ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.32-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.32-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: This question is already answered on [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289567/unmet-dependencies-while-trying-to-install-mysql-in-ubuntu-20-04).

Comment: MySQL 5.x is no supported on Ubuntu 22.04 so, before breaking your database, you may want to make some backups of your data. A `mysqldump` will be sufficient. This will allow you to restore in the event a 5.8⇢8.x upgrade breaks your databases.

Answer (score 0):

libmysqlclient21, mysql-common, mysql-server and mysql-community-server packages are preventing you from upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to  Ubuntu 22.04, so back up your databases and uninstall them.

```
sudo apt autoremove libmysqlclient21 mysql-client mysql-community-test mysql-server
```

If any other new unmet dependencies show up remove them too with `sudo apt autoremove`.